# Should I Use PHP as FastCGI?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

I am running an Apache webserver on my Windows machine. It is not generally a public server (most of the little bit of traffic comes from the machine itself, and most of the public traffic comes from crawlers). Basically, it is mostly just for use as a test-bed, development system.

I have read about how running PHP as FastCGI is better (ie faster and more stable) than as an Apache module. However, I really don’t like the idea of multiple PHP.exe processes (I don’t like that Apache has two processes and I’m not even too thrilled with Chromium’s multi-process model).

So I’m wondering if it would be worthwhile to change PHP to FastCGI for this scenario. If it is, how would I configure it? Pretty much all of the information I have seen has been either for non-Windows or for IIS. As I said, I’m running Windows+Apache.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's wrong with a multi-process model?  Most of the working set between each process ends up being shared.

Comment: Nothing wrong per se, I just don’t like the clutter of having extraneous processes running (eg finding unwanted processes in Task Manager becomes more work if there’s extra chaff). Plus, running a new process takes extra time and has a noticeable effect on the system, no matter how brief.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is just a test-bed development system, there will be little advantage/disadvantage from the 'added' speed-up to using FastCGI. You would probably not even notice it. So, there is no reason to do so unnecessarily.

Comment: That makes sense, though I’m kind of keeping eye towards the future.

Comment: Focus on developing your application. When you are ready to deploy, then switch over to FastCGI. You may not even be using Windows/Apache at the time, depending on your hosting provider.